# Instagram: unable to create client in Manage Clients

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

The problem is that in Manage Clients at https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ client was created, 
but it became invalid, the id did not work, i.e. instagram disabled it, the inscription was disabled.
We decided to delete the old client and create a new One, but instagram does not register it. The line of consent and the captcha does not issue. Respectively writes 2 errors:

1.Incorrect Captcha. Try again.

2.Error sending: fill in all required fields.

How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue, and haven't been able to get anywhere with it. The support page for Instagram says to report a bug using the "Report Bug" button on the Developer Dashboard (http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/). If you click that button it takes you to a form that asks if you want to report a bug for the old API or new API. If you select the old API it says "we're not taking bug reports for the old API", if you select new API it takes you to Facebook's developer support page. I created a ticket there, and they told me I had to report it through Instagram's support links. WTF?? That's what I did .....

Anyways, the problem is related to a bunch of javascript errors on that client registration page. I first encountered this problem about 3-4 weeks ago, and it's still around. Feels like IG really doesn't give a crap about their developer community ....